# About a characterization of solvability for Leibniz algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, nonassociative-algebras

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a Leibniz algebra. Then the *derived series* of $\mathcal{L}$ is the series $$\cdots \subset \mathcal{L}^{(2)} \subset \mathcal{L}^{(1)} \subset \mathcal{L}$$ being $$\mathcal{L}^{(1)}≔[\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L}], \hspace{2cm} \mathcal{L}^{(i+1)}≔[\mathcal{L}^{(i)},\mathcal{L}^{(i)}]$$

We recall $\mathcal{L}$ is *solvable* if $\mathcal{L}^{(n)}=0$ for some $ \in \mathbb{N}$

I´ve readen that it is easy to check that $\mathcal{L}$ is solvable if and only if its associated Lie algebra $ie(\mathcal{L})=\{_ :∈ \mathcal{L}\}$ is solvable

but I can't get the prove. Please, help me.

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: See [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2017.1372455).

Comment: Dear Dietrich, I can't access to that paper  :(

Comment: Then try the paper by Jörg  Feldvoss, "Leibniz algebras as non-associative algebras", Propositions $6.1$ and $6.2$. This is freely availabe on arXiv.

Comment: In that paper doesn't appear a proof. Anyway, it is awesome, full of properties, thanks  :)

Comment: Not true, there is a full proof, see page $26$. It is the equivalence of $(i)$ with $(ii)$.

Comment: Ok, but in that paper $L_{Lie}=L/Leib(L)$, where $Leib(L)$ is the ideal spanned by elements $[x,x]$, and it is different to my set of operators $Lie(L)$